# .toPromise() and lastValueFrom() in rxjs

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

I have this observable

```
createMyRecord(): Observable<myRecord> {
        return of(TEMPLATE_DB).pipe(
            mergeMap((template) => doTask(template)),
            mergeMap(() => EMPTY)
        );
    }
```

I call it with

```
await createMyRecord().toPromise();
```

.toPromise() is deprecated, so I would like to change the call with lastValueFrom():

```
await lastValueFrom(createMyRecord());
```

but I receive the following error:

```
EmptyError
no elements in sequence
```

UPDATE: for now, resolved with:

```
 await lastValueFrom(createMyRecord()).catch((err) => {
            if (err instanceof EmptyError) {
                log.info(OK");
            }
        });
```

but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Is there a better solution?

Yes and no.

In your case `mergeMap(_ => EMPTY)` will ensure that your observable completes without emitting a value. Promises resolve to a value or they error. So the only thing to do here that meets the spec is to throw an error.

### A work-around

You can sidestep this by emitting something. For example, here I emit `null` after the source completes:

```ts
createMyRecord(): Observable<myRecord> {
  return of(TEMPLATE_DB).pipe(
    mergeMap((template) => doTask(template)),
    mergeMap(() => EMPTY),
    s => concat(s, of(null as myRecord))
  );
}
```

Now your promise will resolve with a `null` once the observable completes successfully.

### Something idiomatic

Rather than changing your code, you can change how you call it. This way you don't need to worry about how `Observables` and `Promises` interact.

Instead of `await lastValueFrom(createMyRecord());` write:

```ts
createMyRecord().subscribe();
```

Comment: @user1: Sure. Added another solution that doesn't require you to change your observable code at all.

Answer (score 8):

`lastValueFrom` now takes a configuration parameter as its second parameter, and you can specify a default value that will be emitted if the observable is empty:

```
await rxjs.lastValueFrom(observableThing, {defaultValue: "oh no - empty!"})
```