# Rxjs await Observable complete

Tags: async-await, rxjs, observable

I’d like to await the completion of my observable.  It has a takeUntil I receive a value emited from my cancel$ observable.  Its possible that cancel$ emits a valeu befor observable1 even emits its first value.  That will give me an error.

```
  await lastValueFrom(observable1.pipe(takeUntil(cancel$)))

  console.log("myObservable is completed");
```

I found that using the deprecated `await observable1.toPromise()` fixes my problem.  But I'd like to avoid something deprecated.

Comment: please share the code, if possible a stackblitz with details on expected output!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found my answer here : [.toPromise() and lastValueFrom() in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68939645/topromise-and-lastvaluefrom-in-rxjs)

lastValueFrom takes a second parameter where you can define a default value when  nothing has been emitted.